# VBA to concatenate range of cells, separated by delimiter of " OR ", and stop when a blank cell is reached?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate the range A2:A200, separated by " OR ", but have the VBA stop once it reaches a blank cell. How do I adjust the VBA I am using to stop when it reaches a blank cell?

Here is my VBA function:

```vb
Sub vba_concatenate()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As String
    Dim SourceRange As Range

    Set SourceRange = Range("A2:A200")

    For Each Rng In SourceRange
        i = i & Rng & " OR "
    Next Rng
    Range("C1").Value = Trim(i)

End Sub
```

I've tried finding other VBA's that do this but I cannot find one. I used the code above but once it reaches a blank cell, it adds multiple copies of " OR " until it reaches the end of the range.

Comment: Try adding `If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then; i = i & Rng & " OR "; End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub vba_concatenate()
    Dim Rng As Range 
    Dim i As String 
    Dim SourceRange As Range

  Set SourceRange = Range("A2:A200")

  For Each Rng In SourceRange 
    If LenB(Rng) > 0 Then   'Check if Rng is empty
       If LenB(i)=0 Then
          i =  Rng   'First item
       Else
          i = i & " OR " & Rng  'Append to string
       End If
    Else
       Exit For
    End If
  Next Rng 

  Range("C1").Value = Trim(i)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It is mostly working, but it does add an extra " OR " at the end of the concatenated range. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: See Edited version with  If LenB(I)=0 then

Comment: Hi @qplsn99  if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and gives you some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Get it done w/o loop.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
     Range("C1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value), " OR ")
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [WorksheetFunction.Transpose method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm137117)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Join function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008915)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

---

Actually, you can consider using formual.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" OR ",TRUE,A1:A200)
```